# Несколько аргументов в @property.setter, возможно ли?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Доброго здоровья, уважаемые эксперты!**

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке.

Имею некий код:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = None
        self.__y = None

    @property
    def xy(self):
        return self.__x, self.__y

    @xy.setter
    def xy(self, val_x, val_y):
        self.__x = val_x
        self.__y = val_y
```

так вот, если использовать `@property`, то не получается принять и обработать второй аргумент в сеттере. Можно, конечно, передать в виде кортежа, списка или словаря, а потом распаковать, но всё это не то.

Все примеры, которые удалось найти были только с одним аргументом. Или @property.setter не поддерживает такой возможности и лучше использовать обычные методы?

Comment: А как вы предполагаете запись в xy? Если `a.xy = 1, 2`, то это именно передача кортежа

Comment: Ну да, через запятую. Или в скобках, как при обычной функции, если аргументов несколько.

Comment: В скобках или через запятую - это кортеж (независимо от того, хотите ли вы этого или нет). В сеттере принимайте одним аргументом, и распаковывайте в отдельные поля.

Comment: Ну, т.е. в случае с проперти про именованные аргументы и значения по умолчанию можно забыть, так?

Comment: Проперти - это сущность, прикидывающаяся обычным полем класса. У обычного поля класса нет никаких именованных аргументов или значений по-умолчанию - есть только одно значение. Если вам нужно все это, то используйте просто метод класса.

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснение! Теперь стало понятно!

Answer (score 1):

Додумался до такого варианта с применением функции `property()`:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = 12
        self.__y = 42

    def get_var(self):
        return f'X: {self.__x}, Y: {self.__y}'

    def set_var(self, val, val2=None):
        if val2 is not None:
            self.__y = val2

        self.__x = val

    var = property(get_var, set_var)

a = A()
print(a.var)  # X: 12, Y: 42
a.var = 678
print(a.var) # X: 678, Y: 42
a.set_var(3, 77)
print(a.var)  # X: 3, Y: 77
```

т.е., если аргумент сеттера классически один, то работаем как с атрибутом `a.var = 678`. Если аргументов несколько, то можно **явно** вызвать метод сеттера (при этом он не должен быть приватным!), указанный в `property()`, как обычный метод и передать второй аргумент, который может быть корректно обработан.

Comment: В итоге, не понятно зачем это (какую проблему это решает). Можно было оставить просто два отдельных поля.

Comment: Мне кажется, что удобство в сокращении передаваемых параметров, если второй (третий и т.д.) параметр не обязателен: a.var = 678 или a.set_var(1, 2) выглядит удобнее, чем a.var = 678; a.var2 = 5454.
В общем, мне это надо было для ввода значений температуры, где обязательный параметр - числовое значение, а второй тип шкалы, который по умолчанию в Цельсиях, если явно не задано иное. Программа должна "знать" в каких единицах были введены данные, чтобы правильно произвести конвертацию.

Comment: Зачем для хранения температуры два поля?

Comment: Одно для числового значения, второе для типа шкалы (цельсий, фаренгейт...)

Comment: Вот для такой реализации мне это надо было: [пример](https://pastebin.com/muD8AJY4)

Comment: Ок. Вообще немного нелогично, что геттер возвращает строковой вид. Для этого есть смысл `__str__` или `__repr__` реализовать, а через `get_temperature(self, scale=None)` возвращать числовое значение температуры в шкале по-умолчанию или указанной шкале (и вообще я бы убрал property, но это уже дело вкуса). Также лучше не делать `exit()` при ошибке, а бросать исключение.

Comment: @insolor, вы правы, это больше утрированный пример, чем реально рабочий вариант. Лучше, если геттер будет возвращать кортеж (или другое перечисление) для дальнейшей обработки результата. И да, определенно только исключения (отголоски PHP, извините)). А почему я заморочился именно проперти, чтобы вводить данные ленивому человеку было легче/проще/меньше для аналогичного функционала )))